# How to use if and only if condition in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
       DATE mb
1: May 2013  3
2: Apr 2014  2
3: Nov 2015  5
4: Nov 2014  3
5: Nov 2015  4
```

I want the the row(s) in which `DATE == 'Nov 2015'`, **if an only if** its previous row has `DATE == 'Nov 2014'`. For example, the 5th row.

If I do `mb[DATE=='Nov 2015']` I will get **mb** value **5** and **4** (having DATE = Nov 2015).

So, I tried the following:

```
mb[DATE=='Nov 2015'] | length(mb[DATE=='Nov 2015'])-1==(DATE=='Nov 2014')
```

But the result is `NA`.

I don't know whether **If and only if** (I used here '|') works or not?

Comment: Here I used '||' instead of '|'.

Comment: Is `mb` the dataset and the column at the same time?

Comment: Yes, mb is the dataset with corresponding Date.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity, please check. Can you please clarify if it is the **immediate** previous row, or **any** previous row?

Answer (score 2):

You can use shift:

```
mb[DATE=='Nov 2015' & shift(DATE)=='Nov 2014']
```

**if and only if** is AND(`&`), not OR(`|`)

Comment: Yes, you are right about the notation. But my problem is little different what you understand. I want "Nov 2015" values which has previous column "Nov 2014" because my "mb" value is dependent with previous DATE. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain this better (expand the example maybe)? How is mb related to previous rows? When you say which *has previous column "Nov 2014", do you mean previous rows? Also, do you mean the row immediately before or any column that is before the 'Nov 2015'?

Comment: @TikaRamGurung you are making zero sense. This answer gives you the output you are looking for.

Comment: mb value is already result of two time period, so  it is time dependent. And in your answer how can I use 'shift'? Is this function?

Comment: @TikaRamGurung, `shift` is a function that (without any further parameters) returns a list of the lag row (i.e. previous row)

Comment: @toto_tico, I used package 'move' and its not giving answer but error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shift’ for signature ‘"yearmon"’ . So how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @TikaRamGurung, this seems to be an unrelated problem to the original question, you should post a different question. I am not familiar with the `move` package, though it could be that the `move` package don't use `data.table`, but `data.frame` structure. You can convert a `data.frame` by simple calling the function `data.table`, e.g. `mydatatable <- data.table(mydataframe)`